# How to avoid outdated personal branch from being pushed and merged to master branch

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, git-flow

Currently our dev teams are using following git flow: we have a master branch, a release branch and couple personal branches. The personal branches (both remote and local) are created and managed by developers themself for saving undone works. The master branch and release branch are protected, none developer can merge its personal branch to either master or release branch, unless he creates a pull request and get passed. For now, such method works fine for us, but still, there is a problem:

The developer should pull changes and merge the master branch to his own branch before he start the work, in case their branch become outdated. But from time to time, there is always someone forget to do this and causes some troubles. For instance, some files' implementation has changed on the master, but one who forget to update their branch might still working on the old version. When he finishs the work and want to merge the changes to the master, he realizes the branch is outdated, and eventually, when he pull changes and merge from master, tedious merge conflicts occurs and he have to fix them.

So, for this problem, I am looking for some automatic tools that can help us elimilates such problem. If anyone have ideas about that, or have ideas to improve our current git flow model, please leave an answer below, thanks!

Comment: reviewers who reviews the PR must tell the developer who create the PR to merge/rebase their changes on top of latest master/prod. Otherwise you can try to look at pre-receive hook to reject (not recommended) or remind developers that their pushed commits is not on top of latest master/prod

Comment: "but one who forget to update their branch might still working on the old version, and causes tedious merge conflicts to be fixed." So what? They go "oh!" And merge master now (or rebase onto it) and fix things locally and push again to the pull request. Or close the pull request and start over! No big deal. The point is, the tool you are looking for is called Brain.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what you've described is not gitflow. In gitflow there's 2 persistent branches; `master` (a.k.a. main) and `develop`. Only hotfix branches should be branched from master, while feature (and release) branches should be branched from develop. See [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) for good description of gitflow. Here's a diagram from that link to illustrate how it works:

[image]

To solve you're particular problem (with gitflow), make `master` and `develop` require PR (to merge code) and also disable force push. This means if there's new code in 'master' (for hotfixes) and 'develop` (for features) that is not in the hotfix/feature branch being merged, the developer will need to rebase their changes on top of master or develop respectively. *Note: this approach can also be used in other branching strategies to prevent the issue your team is experiencing.*

Finally, there's a gitflow extension [here](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) that might help your team implement gitflow correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to this problem is to instruct all the developers to *never* check out any shared branches! In other words, never check out `master` or `release` (or `develop` if you have it). Then, anytime you want to branch off of `master`, fetch and branch off of `origin/master` instead. Same with rebasing. Rebase often onto `origin/master` instead of local `master`. It's also faster and more efficient this way (compared to switching to local copies of the shared branches and constantly having to update them).

The other thing I instruct developers to do is to always have a view of the log of their branch open while they're working on it. Every time they commit, amend, rebase, etc, it should be refreshed. This way they will spot right away if something doesn't look right. And, in the case of starting from an old version of `master`, they would see that too right from the start, before they even make their first commit, since the top commit of their branch would be old.

As a side note, I agree with [matt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68310650/how-to-avoid-outdated-personal-branch-from-being-pushed-and-merged-to-master-bra#comment120729395_68310650), of "so what?" Because even if you branch off of a really old version of `origin/master` (perhaps because you started working on the feature branch 6 months ago and just now came back to it), simply rebase onto the latest `origin/master` and fix any merge conflicts you have. Merge conflicts are a regular fact of life in programming teams, and typically can be quickly resolved by 1 person as long as intent is obvious on both sides.